# Как отслеживать перемотку ListView

Tags: java, android, adapter, cursoradaper

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view,Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_1));
    String time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(key));
    if(cursor.getPosition() % 2 == 0){
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(name);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText(time);
    }
    else {
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3)).setText(name);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView4)).setText(time);

    }
}
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(cursor.getPosition() % 2 == 0) { // Чтобы менять попеременно цвет в ListView
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_1, parent, false);
    }
    else {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_2, parent, false);
    }
    return view;
}
```

Это мой класс наследованный от SimpleCursorAdapter. Заливаю базу данных в listview. Хочу сделать так чтобы цвета отдельного listview менялись попеременно. Но cursor при резкой перемотки вниз или вверх сходит сума и отследить следующий view невозможно как у меня с помощью позиции курсора. Как это можно реализовать. Повторяю мне нужно чтобы в SimpleCursorAdapter цвета отдельных view-элементов менялось попеременно двумя цветами.

Comment: Наберите в поиске по этому сайту: getItemViewType , много раз уже отвечали на такой вопрос.

Comment: Переходите на `RecyclerView`, намного удобнее